# packer command run with sudo -E does not work

Tags: centos, packer, oraclelinux

I installed packer on centos and ran "sudo -E packer version" and the command got stuck until I killed it with ctrl+C

However, I don't get this issue with Ubuntu or when running without sudo

issue seems to be happening with RedHat Linux Builds including Oracle Linux and CentOS, I disabled SELinux but still did not work
I downloaded earlier version of packer 1.6, did not work
I tried with terraform (sudo terraform version it WORKED)
Only running Packer with "sudo packer" in Redhat family that does not work

And I need to run it in Oracle Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There used to be a conflict for packer on RHEL.

```
#packer on redhat/oracle linux/centos
/usr/share/cracklib/pw_dict.pwd: Permission denied
/usr/share/cracklib/pw_dict: Permission denied
```

The solution I used was this:

Invoke the packer binary using the absolute path /usr/local/packer
or symlink with a different name packer.io

Best of luck!